# Moose how to change the attribute value only when it is $undef?

Tags: perl, moose

Now have:

```
has 'id' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str',
    default => sub { "id" . int(rand(1000))+1 }
);
```

Works OK, the:

```
PKG->new(id => 'some'); #the id is "some"
PKG->new()              #the id is #id<random_number>
```

In the next scenario:

```
my $value = undef;
PKG->new(id => $value);
```

(of course) got an error:

```
Attribute (id) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'Str' with value undef at /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/site_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Moose/Exception.pm line 37
```

The question is:

How to achieve changing the value after it is set to undef (and only when it is $undef)? So,

```
has 'id' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str|Undef',  #added undef to acceptable Type
    default => sub { "id" . int(rand(1000))+1 }
);
```

Now, it accepting the `$undef`, but I don't want `$undef` but want `"id" . int(rand(1000))+1`. How to change the attribute value **after** it is set?

The `after` is called only for the accessors not for constructors. Maybe some weird `coercion` from `Undef` to `Str` - but *only* for this one attribute?

Ps: using the `PKG->new( id => $value // int(rand(10000)) )` is not an acceptable solution. The module *should* accept the `$undef` and should silently change it to the random number.

Comment: Do you want to change undef to a random value after using a setter, too? Are you after a trigger?

Comment: Check out the BUILD method in moose http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1204/lib/Moose/Manual/Construction.pod#BUILD

Comment: But what about `$obj->id(undef)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Type::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/release/Type-Tiny) has as one of its aims to make it easy to add coercions to individual attributes really easy. Here's an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    package Local::Test;
    use Moose;
    use Types::Standard qw( Str Undef );

    my $_id_default = sub { "id" . int(rand(1000)+1) };

    has id => (
        is      => 'rw',
        isa     => Str->plus_coercions(Undef, $_id_default),
        default => $_id_default,
        coerce  => 1,
    );

    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
}

print Local::Test->new(id => 'xyz123')->dump;
print Local::Test->new(id => undef)->dump;
print Local::Test->new->dump;
```

You could also look at [MooseX::UndefTolerant](https://metacpan.org/release/MooseX-UndefTolerant) which makes `undef` values passed to the constructor act as if they were entirely omitted. This won't cover passing undef to accessors though; just constructors.

Comment: A **LOT** of documetation for an `Tiny` module :) - but it seems be a GREAT module for many things... Need RTFM, but for this - it works. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative, using Moose' BUILD method, which is called after an object is created.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Test;
use Moose;

has 'id' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str|Undef',
);

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    unless($self->id){
        $self->id("id" . (int(rand(1000))+1));
    }
}
1;

package Main;


my $test = Test->new(id => undef);
print $test->id; ###Prints random number if id=> undef
```

More info on BUILD here:
http://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Construction#BUILD

Comment: Nice! Without any external modules. Thanx! :)

Answer (score 0):

@choroba in a comment mentioned about the [triggers](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1204/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod#Triggers). Based on this, found a next solution. The trigger is called twice in the case `id=>undef`, but otherwise it works.

```
use Modern::Perl;

package My;
use namespace::sweep;
use Moose;

my $_id_default = sub { "id" . int(rand(100_000_000_000)+1) };
my $_check_id = sub { $_[0]->id(&$_id_default) unless $_[1] };

has id => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str|Undef',
    default => $_id_default,
    trigger => $_check_id,
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;

say My->new->id;
say My->new(id=>'aaa')->id;
say My->new(id=>undef)->id;
```